# KML in QGis with additional Data

Tags: qgis, kml

i´ve developed a android app that extracts the exif-information of a photo and creates a KML-file (Placemark) - some additional information like camera-type, focal length,... are stored in the tag "ExtendedData".
When i try to import the KML-file in qgis the attribute table only shows the name and description field.

is it possible to import a the KML-file in qgis without loosing any information stored in "ExtendedData"?

The KML-File is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Placemark>
<name>20130404_132050</name>
<ExtendedData>
<Data name="Orientierung">
<displayName>Orientierung</displayName>
<value>1</value>
</Data>
<Data name="Brennweite">
<displayName>Brennweite</displayName>
<value>279/100</value>
</Data>
</ExtendedData>
<Point>
<coordinates>15.448561,47.11721,0</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
</kml>
```

Attributes in Qgis:
[image]

Hope you can help me!
thanks,
michael

EDIT: ok works fine now - i did not had the newest version of QGIS (2.0.1), the KML-File gets importet now correctly with all the attributes in "ExtendedData"

[image]

Comment: There is a Photo2Shape plugin for QGIS already.  It doesn't store all the extra details that you mention but does include lat, lon, altitude and filename as attributes.  So perhaps you could learn from their code or, better yet, work with the developers to extend it.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the kml to a shapefile and then associate the headers and lat lon based on the lat lon. Introduce a schema such as numbering to help or ID the points.