# QGIS difference between Mac OSx and Windows

Tags: qgis, kml, mac, windows

I try to import a KML-Placemark file with QGIS (--> Add Vectorlayer, UTF-8). When i import the File with my Mac (OS 10.6) i don´t have any problems viewing all the attributes stored in the KML-File (they are stored in the Tag "ExtendedData")

[image]

but when i import the same KML-File in the same QGis Version on a Windows 8 OS i only see the attributes "Name" and "Description" (The points are shown correctly)

[image]

this is referring to my question here:
[KML in QGis with additional Data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73174/kml-in-qgis-with-additional-data)
i thought the problem is solved but it is only to 50 % :)

here is my updated kml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<Placemark id="PM1">
<TimeStamp>
        <when>2007-01-14T21:05:02Z</when>
      </TimeStamp>
<name>Data1</name>
<description>AA</description>
<ExtendedData>
<Data name="Orientierung">
<displayName>Orientierung</displayName>
<value>1</value></Data>
<Data name="Brennweite">
<displayName>Brennweite</displayName>
<value>279/100</value>
</Data>
<Data name="Datum">
<displayName>Datum</displayName>
<value>2013:04:04 13:20:49</value>
</Data>
<Data name="Pfad">
<displayName>Pfad</displayName>
<value>file:///C:\Temp\20130404_132050.JPG</value>
</Data>
<Data name="Kamera">
<displayName>Kamera</displayName>
<value>GT-P3110</value></Data>
</ExtendedData>
<Point>
<coordinates>15.448561,47.11721,0</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>

<Placemark id="PM2">
<TimeStamp>
        <when>2007-01-14T21:05:02Z</when>
      </TimeStamp>
<name>Data2</name>
<description>AA</description>
<ExtendedData>
<Data name="Orientierung">
<value>5</value></Data>
<Data name="Brennweite">
<value>400/400</value>
</Data>
<Data name="Datum">
<value>2013:04:04 13:20:50</value>
</Data>
<Data name="Pfad">
<value>file:///C:\Temp\HUGO.JPG</value>
</Data>
<Data name="Kamera">
<value>GT-P3110</value></Data>
</ExtendedData>
<Point>
<coordinates>16.458561,48.15721,0</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
</Document>

</kml>
```

does anyone know why this problem is appearing?? hope you can help me!
thanks michik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The QGIS version of Mac OS X (Dufour -  KyngChaos) uses GDAL 1.10.1

[image]

While the standalone Windows version use GDAL 1.9.X (32 bits) or GDAL 1.10.0 (64 bits)

[image]
and

> It seems that the Windows 2.0 standalone installer is packaged wrong. It seems to include outdated and removed plugins. plugin_installer, osm_export, mapserver_export. None of these work with 2.0 and have been removed from the source not sure why they are showing up in in the final build, or even how. 
>   Nathan Woodrow in [QGIS 2.0 Win standalone busted](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-2-0-Win-standalone-busted-td5078946.html)

Comment: Thank you gene! Do you know if its possible to change the GDAL Version within the Windows standalone to 1.10.1 manually? Maybe replace the .dll or something like this?